# what are the constraints when executing powercli scripts on vsphere trial version

Tags: scripting, virtual-machine, vsphere, powercli

I want to Execute Vsphere Power-cli scripts which can make my tasks easier(Such as configuring firewall,..using the script), however i wanted to know if its possible to run the script on Vsphere client trail version because it only features read-only API unlike the full version which has both read/write API's

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use PowerCLI to get information about your environment, you still will be able to do that.  However, you will not be able to execute any commands that will create/modify values.